# How to send form data to API post via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a form in my project and when it is submitted I need to send the data to an API and receive the response to check if there's an errors

the html

```
<form id="contactForm" class="w-75 mx-auto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control bg-transparent" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" class="form-control bg-transparent my-3" placeholder="E-mail">
    <textarea class="form-control bg-transparent" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="my-3 px-4 py-2 rounded-3">SEND</button>
</form>
```

the js

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: To what API and endpoint do you need to send it to? I see you're using jQuery, have you looked into the [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) documentation to send HTTP request with JavaScript? I would recommend learning how to find the answer you're looking for with search engines, as there are guaranteed to be a lot of examples and tutorials on this subject. Nevertheless, we'll help you out.

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/2424652](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/2424652)

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Make sure URL for API and web should be the same else you could get cross site error:

```
<form id="contactForm" class="w-75 mx-auto" action="http://yourAPI.com">
    <input type="text" class="form-control bg-transparent" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" class="form-control bg-transparent my-3" placeholder="E-mail">
    <textarea class="form-control bg-transparent" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="my-3 px-4 py-2 rounded-3">SEND</button>
</form>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

        
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data); // show server response 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch` api and the `POST` method to send data to an api.
Since you have not provided how your api works or how the data is to be passed I cannot provide further help, but i can guide you to the correct path.

[Read more about fetch api in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
(async function () {
    const url = ''; // your api endpoint here
    const res = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST' });
    // res corresponds to the api response;
})();
```

Since you're using jQuery, you should probably read [jQuery post method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#contactForm").submit( async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        name: e.target.elements[0].value,
        email: e.target.elements[1].value,
        message: e.target.elements[2].value,
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when- 
       downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict- 
       origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
       body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('variable1', variable1);
formData.append('variable2', variable2);

url = `url`
options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
}

let response = await request(url, options)
```

Comment: This answer lacks some important pieces . It uses an undefined function(request) and doesn't explain what you are doing